# How to send JSON raw via POST Request on Android API Level 22

Tags: java, android, json

Currently I'am debugging my Java Code as follows:

```
public void sign_in(View view) {
    String json = "";

    // The Username & Password
    final EditText em =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
    String email = (String) em.getText().toString();
    final EditText pw =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    String password = (String) pw.getText().toString();
    // -----------------------


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        HttpResponse response;
        jsonObject.accumulate("email", email);
        jsonObject.accumulate("password", password);
        json = jsonObject.toString();
        URL url = new URL("http://cloudspecinc.herokuapp.com/api/user/login/");
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        String sresponse = response.getEntity().toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());

    } finally {
        /* nothing to do here */
    }

}
```

My question:

1. How can I get the response of the POST Request? It's not yet in the
   code because I don't know how to get it.
2. The severe problem: When i click the "LOG IN" button the app always
   crashes. (NOTE: It compiles on android studio but crashes
       when I click the "LOG IN" button that trigger the sign in function).

Something that I think the problem is:

1. HttpClient is deprecated in Android API Level 22. (Android 5.1
   Lollipop API Level 22)
2. Something is wrong with the code.

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated, so you should use HttpURLConnection. Also, please post your logcat here

Comment: Looks like the main issue is that you're doing a network operation in the main UI thread.  Use an AsyncTask.

Comment: I suggest investing some of your time trying a networking library like [volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/request.html#request-json).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK Now I know.. Requesting HTTP Type Request must be on a AsyncTask. not on the current thread because it will throw an exception when not on a Asynchronous Class due to Network Threading Exception. I forgot what the Exception is called. I'am only a beginner on Java. because I'am not really a Java programmer.

Here is the code to help others on this kind of problem.

```
public class REST extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        String json = null;
        // The Username & Password
        final EditText em =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        String email = (String) em.getText().toString();
        final EditText pw =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        String password = (String) pw.getText().toString();
        // -----------------------

        try {
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("email", email);
            jsonObject.accumulate("password", password);
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://cloudspecinc.herokuapp.com/api/user/login/");
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String sresponse = response.getEntity().toString();
            Log.w("QueingSystem", sresponse);
            Log.w("QueingSystem", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());

        } finally {
        /* nothing to do here */
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (result != null) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // error occured
        }
    }
}
```